# Expension file in Android

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am working on creating an expension file in android. i have facing some issues in this :

for testing purpose , i create a .zip file which contains some videos then save it .obb extension. Now file in my SD card is main.1.com.xyz.abc.obb.zip

now i am facing some issue in reading file . Code for doing this :

```
String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, true, 1);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "Android"
                + File.separator + "obb" + File.separator + fileName+".zip";
        InputStream ins = getExpansionFile().getInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "Android"
                          + File.separator + "obb" + File.separator + fileName+File.separator+"video123.mp4");
        String name=ins.toString();




public ZipResourceFile getExpansionFile() {

    String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, true, 1);

            int filesize = 108902927;
    if (Helpers.doesFileExist(this, fileName+".zip",filesize , false)) {

        try {
            return APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(
                    getBaseContext(), 1, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;       
    }
```

Now

```
InputStream ins = getExpansionFile().getInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "Android"
                          + File.separator + "obb" + File.separator + fileName+File.separator+"video123.mp4");
```

method returns null.

Please provide me any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> getExpansionFile().getInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "Android"
>                             + File.separator + "obb" + File.separator + fileName+File.separator+"video123.mp4");;

The error is that the files in the ZipResourceFile are mapped by relative paths, not absolute ones. In this case, the key to get your file from the ZipResourceFile is just

> fileName + File.separator + "video123.mp4"